Error creating new account using mint
While trying to create new accounts I am having issues. Could be accounts cannot be created after disabling mint.
spl-token create-account mntZFtv8SvH6trqeSwvTGPVSXXXXXXXXX --owner reserve.json

Error:
Creating account 36zWT5n9jjPLQ9XD4fHDzwEdZXXXXXXXXXXXX
Error: Client(Error { request: Some(SendTransaction), kind: RpcError(RpcResponseError { code: -32002, message: "Transaction simulation failed: Attempt to debit an account but found no record of a prior credit.", data: SendTransactionPreflightFailure(RpcSimulateTransactionResult { err: Some(AccountNotFound), logs: Some([]), accounts: None, units_consumed: Some(0), return_data: None, inner_instructions: None }) }) })


You might be trying to create the token account but the signer of the tx doesn't have funds to perform this operation.
Can you airdrop some SOL to the signer of the transaction.
solana airdrop 2


This works instead
spl-token create-account mntZFtv8SvH6trqeSwvTGPVSXXXXXXXXX reserve.json --immutable

